# Gephi: Multiplex/Mulitlayer Networks

Tags: gephi, graph-visualization

I am relatively new to Gephi. I have created two networks with the same nodes, but with different edges and edge weights. I did this in two seperated projects.

Is there a way in Gephi to layer the networks over each other so that one get a nice multiplex network representation?

If not, are there any good (and easy) alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: Did you create the networks manually?

Comment: The networks are obtained from real data at two different points of times. I was looking for a nice multilayer representation of the network to illustrate changes. But I think Gephi has no features for that, so I think the best way is to do both networks separately.